# The ratio of the volume of a trihedron in a ball to the volume of that ball

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, convex-analysis, lebesgue-measure

> In $\mathbb{R}^3$ consider the convex body defined as 
>   $$C=\left\{(x, y,z): x \geq 0, y \geq 0, z-x-y \geq 0\right\}.$$

Let $B(0,r)$ denote the open ball of radius $r>0$ with the center at zero. I am thinking about the following questions:

a)  Is it true that the ratio $\frac{V(C\cap B(0,r))}{V(B(0,r))}$ does not depend on $r$?
(My conjecture is that this is not necessarily so.)

b)  If a) is not true then is it possible to show that the ratio $\frac{V(C\cap B(0,r))}{V(B(0,r))}$ is bounded from below by a positive constant for any $r>0$?
(My conjecture would be yes but I don’t know how to show this.)

c)  Can the conclusion either in a) or b) be reached for any convex body $C$ with non-empty interior in $\mathbb{R}^3$ obtained by the intersection of a finite number of half-spaces containing $(0,0,0)$?

I would greatly appreciate any hints on how to possibly approach these questions.

Comment: why don't you try to calculate something?

Comment: I can try to calculate something but I thought that maybe there are some general principles (unknown to me) from which the answers to my questions are more or less obvious. Especially the answer to c) since the calculations are not likely to help with that.

Comment: Do you know anything about similarity in space? By the way, your conjectures are wrong.

Comment: No, I don't know anything about similarity in space. But will check it now. All my conjectures are wrong?

Comment: If you know how to find a volume using an integral I'd suggest to compute the volume of $C\cap B(0,r))$ to show that it is simply $k\times r^3$, where $k$ is a constant.

Comment: Will try that. Thanks.

Comment: The shade $C$ can be viewed as a union of rays originated at the origin. The "ratio" of intersection of any shape like this with a ball of radius $r$ centered at same origin doesn't depends on $r$ at all. It is equal to the solid angle of such shape at that origin.

Comment: @achille hui : thanks, can I read somewhere about this?

Comment: I'm not aware of anyplace which specifically discuss this. Another way to look at this is consider the scaling transform $x \mapsto \frac{x}{r}$. It maps the $C \cap B(0,r)$ to $ C \cap B(0,1)$. Since the Jacobian of this sort of transform is independent of $x$, the ratio of volumes is invariant under such a transform.

Comment: @achille hui: Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As achille hui explained, the scaling transformation $x\mapsto \frac{x}{r}$ can be used to answer this, and in greater generality.

Let $C$ be any *cone*, meaning a set such that $x\in C\implies rx\in C$ for all $r>0$. All sets $C$ you consider are cones in this sense.

The scaling transform $x\mapsto x/r$ maps $C\cap B(0,r)$ onto $C\cap B(0,1)$. The Jacobian determinant of this transform is $r^n$. Hence, 
$$\frac{\operatorname{vol}(C\cap B(0,r)}{\operatorname{vol}(C\cap B(0,1)} = r^n$$